# Linux Command to Show Stopped and Running processes?

Tags: c, linux, process, execvp

I'm presently executing the following Linux command in one of my c programs to display processes that are running. Is there anyway I can modify it to show stopped processes and running ones?

```
char *const parmList[] = {"ps","-o","pid,ppid,time","-g","-r",groupProcessID,NULL};
execvp("/bin/ps", parmList);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make a system call to get list of processes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408766/make-a-system-call-to-get-list-of-processes)

Answer (score 14):

`jobs -s` [list **s**topped](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) process by `SIGTSTP` (20), [no `SIGSTOP`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) (19). [The main difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11888074/4970442) is that `SIGSTOP` cannot be ignored. More info with `help jobs`.

You can `SIGTSTP` a process with `^Z` or from other shell with `kill -TSTP PROC_PID` (or with `pkill`, see below), and then list them with `jobs`.

But what about listing PIDs who had received **SIGSTOP**? [One way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/350674/209677) to get this is

```
 ps -A -o stat,command,pid | grep '^T '
```

From [`man ps`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html#PROCESS_STATE_CODES):

> `-A`     Select all processes.  Identical to `-e`.
>
> `T` stopped by job control signal

---

I found very useful this two to stop/cont for a while some process (usually the browser):

```
kill -STOP $(pgrep procName)
kill -CONT $(pgrep procName)
```

Or with [`pkill` or `killall`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91708/209677):

```
pkill -STOP procName
pkill -CONT procName
```

Comment: In my case, `jobs -l` helped me to find the PID of a proccess stoped by `^Z`.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to @pablo-bianchi, he gave me the oompff (starting point) to find SIGSTOP'd and SIGTSTP'd processes, however his answers are not completely correct.

Pablo's command should use `T` rather than `S`

```
$ ps -e -o stat,command,pid | grep '^T '
T    /bin/rm -r 2021-07-23_22-00 1277441
T    pyt 999                     1290977
$ ps -e -o stat,command,pid | grep '^S ' | wc -l
153
$
```

From `man ps`:

```
PROCESS STATE CODES
       Here are the different values that the s, stat and state output specifiers (header "STAT"
       or "S") will display to describe the state of a process:

               D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
               I    Idle kernel thread
               R    running or runnable (on run queue)
               S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
               T    stopped by job control signal
               t    stopped by debugger during the tracing
               W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
               X    dead (should never be seen)
               Z    defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent
```

WRT `pgrep`, it is a real grep, the argument is NOT a program name; rather, it is a *regular expression* applied to the first item in /proc//cmdline (*usually* the name from the executing commandline (or execve()).

Therefore if you are trying to kill `pyt`, you would accidentally also kill all the python programs that are running:

```
$ pgrep -a pyt
7228 python3 /home/wwalker/bin/i3-alt-tab-ww --debug
1290977 pyt 999
```

You need to "anchor" the regular expression:

```
$ pgrep -a '^pyt$'
1290977 pyt 999
```

Answer (score 0):

`ps -e`  lists all processes.

`jobs` list all processes currently stopped or in background.

So, you can run `jobs` command using `execvp`:

```
char *arg = {"jobs", NULL};
execvp(arg[0], arg);
```

Comment: I have to use ps, and I need to make sure that both running and stopped processes are shown

Comment: Job control and their commands are specific to the *shell*, there is no general `jobs` command, it's a shell built-in command.

Comment: @Vimzy, if you only need that both running and stopped processes are shown (and you don't need to differentiate), you can use `ps -e`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, does that mean `jobs` can't be used using `execvp`. I have not tried running this snippet (because I was sure it would work, execvp is used like this)

Comment: -e can't work because it processes that aren't a part of the group process ID

Comment: Correct, there won't be such a command in the filesystem anywhere. Instead it's the shell that catches it and handles it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, thanks for the insight. @vimzy, I don't really understand what you mean by `it processes that aren't a part of the group process ID`, because man page says it selects all processes. I don't really know but maybe `ps -A` or `ps aux` can be used.